# How to Render a Scaled Pixel Buffer with Xlib/XRender

Tags: c, graphics, x11, xlib

On startup I allocate: `u32 *pixel_buffer = calloc(width * height, 4);`

I wish to render this scaled to the current width and height of the window. My attempts:

1. Using `XCreateImage/XPutImage` renders correctly when the starting
   window dimensions match the dimensions of the pixel buffer. On
   window resize however, the contents of the buffer aren't scaled and
   the extra space is filled in with black (the value of the background
   pixel I set for the window)
2. Use `XPutImage` to a `Pixmap`. Then each loop iteration, use
   `XRenderCreatePicture` on this `Pixmap` and on the `Window` and
   `XRenderComposite` them. This just produces a black screen.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XPutImage(display, pixmap, default_gc, x_image, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, pixel_buffer_width, pixel_buffer_height);

Picture src_pict = XRenderCreatePicture(display, pixmap, pic_format, 0, &pic_attributes);
Picture dst_pict = XRenderCreatePicture(display, window, pic_format, 0, &pic_attributes);

double x_scale = pixel_buffer_width / window_width;
double y_scale = pixel_buffer_height / window_height;
XTransform transform_matrix = {{
  {XDoubleToFixed(x_scale), XDoubleToFixed(0), XDoubleToFixed(0)},
  {XDoubleToFixed(0), XDoubleToFixed(y_scale), XDoubleToFixed(0)},
  {XDoubleToFixed(0), XDoubleToFixed(0), XDoubleToFixed(1.0)}  
}};
XRenderSetPictureTransform(display, src_pict, &transform_matrix);

XRenderComposite(display, PictOpSrc, src_pict, 0, dst_pict, 
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                window_width, window_height);
```